# Anyone implemented/used Mobile Device Screen Orientation plugin?

Tags: plugins, screen-orientation, adobe-analytics

Has anyone successfully implemented **screen orientation plugin** in Sitecatalyst to capture mobile device orientation?. When we use the below code in the s_code,  in the web page i am seeing some unusual behavior(ie: when we scroll the page to the bottom and then if i click anywhere on the content section, page goes to the top by default). I understand, that's happening because of this line "*window.scroll(0,0)*". Any help or thoughts?

**Plugin Code below:**
function screenOrientation(){switch(window.orientation){case 0:case 180:return("Portrait");break;case 90:case -90:return("Landscape");}window.scroll(0,0)}

Reference: [http://webanalyticsland.com/sitecatalyst-implementation/capture-mobile-device-screen-orientation-in-sitecatalyst]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a code bug (or more a typo I think) and the line `window.scroll(0,0)` can be safely removed from the 'plugin' (its not really a plugin, just a js function that returns the orientation).

The reason this fires every time a user clicks on anywhere on the page is because you have ClickMap functionality enabled in your s_code.js configuration.  This will fire an s.tl() everytime a click event occurs.  the s.tl() will call the screenOrientation() function to populate your required prop/eVar.

So if you were to turn off clickMap (`s.trackInlineStats=false;`) this random scrolling to the top would stop even if you didn't remove the offending line.  That said, remove the scrolling code, its not right or required!

Comment: Please don't use signatures or taglines in your posts.